# How to use a material number as a feature for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, features

I have a problem. I want to use a classification algorithm. I also have `materialNumber` as a column. Could I use that as a feature for my Machine Learning algorithm? (I have the materialDescription, but as a catergorial feature I can not use them e.g. as a One Hot Enconding matrix, because there is too much different materials) If yes, do I need to standardize/normalize the `number`? Or what is neccessary to use them.

Comment: Why can't you one-hot encode the categories?

Comment: Because there are several hundreds of different item descriptions. And the model would then become bloated.

Comment: "Bloated" in what sense?